# Magento 2 : How to Load Image Collection in Category Listing Page

Tags: magento2, product-images, magento2.1.6, category-listing

Need to Image gallery collection load to following path in magento 2.1.6 category listing page ,

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\image_with_borders.phtml
```

( Or )

```
app\design\frontend\Magento\{custom-theme}\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\image_with_borders.phtml
```

Anyone please review the question and let me know your suggestions.

Thank you ,

Comment: you want all product image colletion on category page?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya , Yes i want all products images collection for category pages .

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get all gallery images on product list page:

```
<?php
    $Om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $Om->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());        
    $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();

    foreach($images as $image) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image->getUrl(); ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: your code i  already try to this method but not working on category listing page .

Comment: What error you are facing in above code? Can you show how you implement this code on your category page?

Comment: In your code i just past on below path ,
app\design\frontend\Magento\{custom-theme}\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\image_with_borders.phtml

After that i cleared the cache both adminpanel & via ssh and running category page just blanked display .

Please check and let me know your suggestions .

Comment: you need to put the code in proper place where you want to access each product data, you need to put this in foreach loop.

Comment: Yes , but i want below path ,

` app\design\frontend\Magento\{custom-theme}\Magento_Catalog\t‌​emplates\product\ima‌​ge_with_borders.phtm‌​l`

category page list page .

Comment: Still you are facing any issue? You need to get file path by enabling template path hints from admin.

Comment: still i am getting same error ..

Comment: which error you are facing? And post your entire code what you have try? because I use same code.

Comment: please put in your code  following file , `ima‌​ge_with_borders.phtm‌​l `  top section and run the category page . 

I have no issues , but page empty .

Comment: ima‌​ge_with_borders.phtm‌​l in this file you need to access the product data and then try above code. I alredy mension you need to put the data in proper place where you are able to access product object, because product Id need to pass in this code.

Comment: How to load product data in this page . any idea ??